# How to dump SoapServer request for debug in laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, soapserver

There is method getLastRequestHeaders() and getLastRequest() for soapClient.But how can i dump last request in my soapServer in laravel?

Answer (score 0):

SoapServer doesn't have a `getLastRequestHeaders` or `getLastRequest` functions.

When you create a new SoapClient, add `trace` as a parameter:

```
$soap = new SoapClient($$wsdl, array( 'trace' => true );
```

Then you can use:

```
print_r( $soap->__getLastRequest() );
print_r( $soap->__getLastRequestHeaders() );
print_r( $soap->__getLastResponse() );
print_r( $soap->__getLastResponseHeaders() );
```